# How to change drawable shape color based on spinner selection

Tags: android, spinner, drawable

I am trying to figure out how to change the solid color and the stroke color based on the spinner selection.

spin_shape drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#97233F" />
<stroke android:color="#FFC20E"
    android:width="@dimen/button_border" />
</shape>
```

Button with the drawable as a background

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/team_a_td"
    android:background="@drawable/spin_shape"
    android:onClick="addSixForTeamA" />
```

Array resource xml file

```
<array name="color_array">
    <item>#ff0000</item>
    <item>#e9b300</item>
    <item>#db9fd5</item>
</array>
<array name="stroke_color_array">
    <item>#2988BC</item>
    <item>#660006</item>
    <item>#0C6674</item>
</array>
```

Here's what I used to change an image view based on the spinner selection. I want to see if there is something similar I can do to change the shape color and stroke color.

```
String[] listOfObjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.teams_array); 
TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.team_image);
TypedArray team_colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.color_array);
TypedArray secondary_colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.stroke_color_array);
Button team_a_td_color = (Button)findViewById(R.id.team_a_td);
final Spinner spinnerA = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.team_a_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapterA = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item, listOfObjects);
    spinnerAdapterA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerA.setAdapter(spinnerAdapterA);
    spinnerA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
        itemImageA.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(spinnerA.getSelectedItemPosition(), -1));           
}
```

Comment: You need to create a drawable for every colour you want to display, and change the Button background like you change the image in the ImageView

Comment: @Eselfar That's what I've been doing but I was hoping there was a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ways to do that, one is create a custom `Drawable` class, the other is to use different themes.

**Method 1 - custom class**

```
public class MyJavaDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final int fillColor;
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public MyJavaDrawable(int fillColor, int strokeColor, float strokeWidth){
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
        paint.setColor(strokeColor);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(fillColor);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return paint.getAlpha();
    }
}

// ...

MyJavaDrawable drawable = new MyJavaDrawable(fillColor, strokeColor, borderWidthPx);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Since you're not using images but just drawing directly on canvas, you could easily instantiate many of these with different colors. Caveat n.1, I think that the value for `strokeWidthPx` should be doubled there because it is drawing exactly on the edges of the rectangle so half of that width would lay outside of the drawing area. Caveat n.2, the `ImageView` should have well-defined size, if you want to use `wrap_content` I think you should set intrinsic bound to the `Drawable`.

**Method 2 - themes**

In your `styles.xml` define 2 attributes for stroke and fill color, then as many styles as you need, for instance "red" and "blue" styles:

```
<attr name="SpinShapeFillColor" format="color" />
<attr name="SpinShapeStrokeColor" format="color" />

<style name="SpinShapeRed">
    <item name="SpinShapeFillColor">#ffff0000</item>
    <item name="SpinShapeStrokeColor">#ffff9900</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinShapeBlue">
    <item name="SpinShapeFillColor">#ff0000ff</item>
    <item name="SpinShapeStrokeColor">#ff9900ff</item>
</style>
```

Then change your `spin_shape.xml` to reference the attributes you've defined like so:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?attr/SpinShapeFillColor" />
    <stroke android:color="?attr/SpinShapeStrokeColor"
        android:width="@dimen/button_border" />
</shape>
```

Then in your code you need to create a `Resources.Theme` for each style:

```
final Resources.Theme themeBlue = getResources().newTheme();
themeBlue.applyStyle(R.style.SpinShapeBlue, true);

final Resources.Theme themeRed = getResources().newTheme();
themeRed.applyStyle(R.style.SpinShapeRed, true);
```

And finally, you instantiate the `Drawable` with the selected `Theme` and set it to the `ImageView`:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spin_shape, themeBlue);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is, you can create 2 drawables with 2 intended colors of yours and set drawable according to your condition e.g

```
        Drawable drawable
        if(needBlue){
           drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spin_shape_blue);
        }else{
           drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spin_shape_orange);
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: that's exactly what OP is doing, the only difference is that you're proposing to instantiate the `Drawable` and then setting it to the `ImageView` instead of selecting the resource id and then setting the id to the `ImageView`